# How to create legend for react-leaflet-heatmap-layer?

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I've created a heatmap layer using React-Leaflet-Heatmap-Layer.

I've also created a legend that shows color spectrum of heatmap layer.
When mouse moves on heatmap canvas, legend indicator must move to a range of color spectrum that matches the color of pixel which mouse is on that.
I found this link that represents code that detect color of each pixel by mouse move and change backgroundColor of a small div according to hex color of pixel.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas

But in my case I need to detect position of that color hex in my legend spectrum by an indicator.

[image]

[image]

Comment: "legend indicator must move to a range ... " What is the "legend indicator"?  Are you saying you wanta. little arrow to appear over the legend and point to the color that you're currently hovered over?  Or you want the colors on the legend bar to shift as you move the cursor?  Either way, what you're asking is not trivial, so I recommend you make some attempts on your own and ask more specific questions.

Comment: well I mean a little arrow to appear over the legend and point to the color that you're currently hovered over...